# R histogram showing time spent in each bin

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'm trying to create a plot similar to [the ones here](http://www.joefrielsblog.com/2012/07/bike-cadence-and-triathlon-race-distance.html):

[image: Cadence distribution]

Basically I want a histogram, where each bin shows how long was spent in that range of cadence (e.g 1 hour in 0-20rpm, 3 hours in 21-40rpm, etc)

```
library("rjson") # 3rd party library, so: install.packages("rjson")

# Load data from Strava API.
# Ride used for example is http://app.strava.com/rides/13542320
url <- "http://app.strava.com/api/v1/streams/13542320?streams[]=cadence,time"
d <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url)))
```

Each value in `d$cadence` (rpm) is paired with the same index in `d$time` (the number of seconds from the start).

The values are not necessarily uniform (as can be seen if you compare `plot(x=d$time, y=d$cadence, type='l')` with `plot(d$cadence, type='l')` )

If I do the simplest possible thing:

```
hist(d$cadence)
```

..this produces something very close, but the Y value is "frequency" instead of time, and ignores the time between each data point (so the 0rpm segment in particular will be underrepresented)

Comment: What do you mean that the Y value is "frequency"? You mean the label on the Y axis? That can be fixed with `hist(d$cadence, ylab="Time")`.

Comment: Are you saying the *desired* behavior is to ignore the times in between each data point? i.e. the bar originating from 0 represents the number of samples which were *exactly* 0?

Comment: When I tried your code I found that the number == 0 was 4425, and the number < 10 was 4439. So I don't think you'd see a drastic change in the bars when you in/exclude the "time between each data point."

Comment: In the same vein as @DavidRobinson 's comment, you can specify the bin edges with additional arguments to `hist` . That will solve your difficulty with zero-rpm values not being plotted.

Comment: I've worked with data like this before. I believe what the OP wants is to account for uneven time between samples, e.g. if one sample was taken at t=10 with cadence of 95, and the next sample isn't until t=16 with cadence=93, then the metrics should act as if the cadence was 95 for all 10<=t<16. i.e. cadence was 95 for 6 seconds. The standard hist() call treats the "count" of this event as 1, not 6.

Comment: @dbr so then does my answer below address the question? if so, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new column to account for the time between samples.

I prefer data.frames to lists for this kind of thing, so:

```
d <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste(readLines(url))))
d$sample.time <- 0
d$sample.time[2:nrow(d)] <- d$time[2:nrow(d)]-d$time[1:(nrow(d)-1)]
```

now that you've got your sample times, you can simply "repeat" the cadence measures for anything with a sample time more than 1, and plot a histogram of that

```
hist(rep(x=d$cadence, times=d$sample.time),
     main="Histogram of Cadence", xlab="Cadence (RPM)",
     ylab="Time (presumably seconds)")
```

There's bound to be a more elegant solution that wouldn't fall apart for non-integer sample times, but this works with your sample data.

EDIT: re: the more elegant, generalized solution, you can deal with non-integer sample times with something like `new.d <- aggregate(sample.time~cadence, data=d, FUN=sum)`, but then the problem becomes plotting a histogram for something that looks like a frequency table, but with non-integer frequencies. After some poking around, I'm coming to the conclusion you'd have to roll-your-own histogram for this case by further aggregating the data into bins, and then displaying them with a barchart.

Comment: The `rep()` based solution seems to do what I'm after - thanks! The sampling-time will always be integers (if it wasn't, I'd be tempted to make it into a curve and resample it at integer times)

Comment: I'm eager to do a similar thing (with strava streams) in Python/numpy/matplotlib!