# R histogram of timeseries data with duration on y-axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram from time-series data in R, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529146/r-histogram-showing-time-spent-in-each-bin). Each bin should show the total duration for the values falling within the bin. I have non-integer sample times in an zoo object of thousands of rows. The timestamps are irregular, and the data is assumed to be constant between each timestamp (sample-and-hold).

Example data:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("2018-02-21 15:00:00.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:02.5", "2018-02-21 15:00:05.2", "2018-02-21 15:00:07.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:09.3", "2018-02-21 15:00:10.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:12.0"), tz = "GMT")
data  = c(0,3,5,1,3,0,2)
z = zoo(data, order.by = timestamp)
x.df <- data.frame(Date = index(z), Value = as.numeric(coredata(z)))
ggplot(x.df, aes(x = Date, y = Value)) + geom_step() + scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M:%OS"))
```

Please see the [times-series plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJEag.png). Creating a histogram with `hist(z, freq = T)` does not care about the timestamps: [Plot from hist method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvFCw.png).

My desired output is a histogram with duration in seconds on the y-axis, something like this: [Histogram with non-integer duration on y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUz3B.png).

Edit:

I should point out that the data values are not integers, and that i want to be able to control the bin width(s). I could use `diff(timestamp)` to create a (non-integer) column showing duration for each point, and plotting a bar graph like suggested by @MKR:

```
x.df = data.frame(DurationSecs = as.numeric(diff(timestamp)), Value = data[-length(data)])
ggplot(x.df, aes(x = Value, y = DurationSecs)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This gives a histogram with the right bar heights for the example. But this fails when the values are floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found a solution. The answer provided by MKR sort of works, but I could not set the number of bins and it failed for floating-pont values.

I came across the wonderful functions `cut` and `xtab` in this question: [How to plot an histogram with y as a sum of the x values for every bin in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427734/how-to-plot-an-histogram-with-y-as-a-sum-of-the-x-values-for-every-bin-in-ggplot). The solution provided there was painfully slow, drawing each data-point duration as stacked bars.

I don't need separate bars for each data-point, I just need the sum of the durations within each bin. This is my solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("2018-02-21 15:00:00.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:02.5",
"2018-02-21 15:00:05.2", "2018-02-21 15:00:07.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:09.3",
"2018-02-21 15:00:10.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:12.0"), tz = "GMT")
data  = c(0,3,5,1,3,0,2)
z = zoo(data, order.by = timestamp)
x.df <- data.frame(Date = index(z), Value = as.numeric(coredata(z)))

# DurationSecs is added as numeric. It shows diff from the previous datapoint. 
x.df <- x.df %>% arrange(Date) %>%
mutate(DurationSecs = ifelse(is.na(lead(Date)), 0, lead(Date) - Date))

# Adding a column of bins to the dataframe:
BinCount <- 7
x.df$bins = cut(x.df$Value, pretty(x.df$Value, n = BinCount), include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)

# Creating a new dataframe containing bins and the sum of DurationSecs for each bin.
y.df = data.frame(xtabs(DurationSecs ~ bins, x.df))

# Ready to plot
ggplot(y.df, aes(x = bins, y = Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    ylab("Duration") +
    xlab("Value") +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = F) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))
```

The result is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk2mn.png). As a bonus, the labels on the x-axis are really beautiful, and I have the frequency table available for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want `duration (in seconds)` on `y-axis`, hence you should add one column in `x.df` for `duration`. A histogram with `stat = sum` will fit needs of OP. The steps are

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("2018-02-21 15:00:00.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:02.5",
 "2018-02-21 15:00:05.2", "2018-02-21 15:00:07.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:09.3", 
 "2018-02-21 15:00:10.0", "2018-02-21 15:00:12.0"), tz = "GMT")
data  = c(0,3,5,1,3,0,2)
z = zoo(data, order.by = timestamp)
x.df <- data.frame(Date = index(z), Value = as.numeric(coredata(z)))

# DurationSecs is added as numeric. It shows diff from earliest time. 

x.df <- x.df %>% arrange(Date) %>%
mutate(DurationSecs = ifelse(is.na(lead(Date)), 0, lead(Date) - Date))


# Draw the plot now
ggplot(x.df, aes(x = Value, y = DurationSecs)) + geom_histogram(stat="sum")
```

[image]

```
#The data
#                 Date Value DurationSecs
#1 2018-02-21 15:00:00     0          2.5
#2 2018-02-21 15:00:02     3          2.7
#3 2018-02-21 15:00:05     5          1.8
#4 2018-02-21 15:00:07     1          2.3
#5 2018-02-21 15:00:09     3          0.7
#6 2018-02-21 15:00:10     0          2.0
#7 2018-02-21 15:00:12     2          0.0
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the bars are to tall. The duration is the time the signal spent "in the bin". The first bin, in this example `[0,1>`, should be 4.5 seconds (2.5+2). Also, the real values are not integers, and I should be able to control the bin width. I will clarify in my post.

Comment: @Jendem I'm not clear about the calculation of duration. How are you calculating 4.5 for `0 - 1` ? Please explain.

Comment: @Jendem I have updated my solution. Have a look. I think you have to work on legend, labels and color etc. but data should look correct.